# Cannot run npm packages in Windows7

Tags: windows, npm

I forked this project from: (https://github.com/aayusharora/GeneticAlgorithms)

but when I try to run like written in comments:

```
  cd part1
  npm install
  npm run
```

I receive following error:

```
18201 error code EBADPLATFORM
18202 error notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.6: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
18203 error notsup Valid OS:    linux
18203 error notsup Valid Arch:  any
18203 error notsup Actual OS:   win32
18203 error notsup Actual Arch: x64
18204 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Is there anyway to run this project in Win7?

Comment: You can install a Linux subsystem on your PC (I for myself have a Ubuntu app from Canonical Group for executing Linux commands, but it's only a command prompt).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to run the project after starting it in Ubuntu under virtual machine